# Rules for benzene halogenation

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, halides

Can anyone please show me the rule on how a halogen like bromine reacts with benzene, such as when bromine replaces hydrogen? I'm wondering what happens after the first hydrogen is replaced? Does it replace the hydrogen in the 2- or 4-position after that or something else?

Comment: [SEAr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophilic_aromatic_substitution#Effect_of_substituent_groups)

Answer (score 2):

The most common reaction of aromatic compounds is electrophilic
aromatic substitution, in which an electrophile (**E1**) reacts with an aromatic
ring and substitutes for one of the hydrogens.

In an unsubstituted benzene ring, the halogen will likely take any position (essentially any position is the same - just depends on how you draw the structure) since the ring is only attached to hydrogen atoms with similar effect  in the ring system.

The real question is **what would happen if we were to carry out a reaction on an aromatic
ring that already has a substituent?**

A substituent already present on the ring
has two effects:

- Substituents affect the reactivity of the aromatic ring. Some substituents
  activate the ring, making it more reactive than benzene, and some
  deactivate the ring, making it less reactive than benzene. In aromatic
  nitration, for instance, an -OH substituent makes the ring 1000 times
  more reactive than benzene, while an - NO2 substituent makes the ring
  more than 10 million times less reactive.
- Substituents affect the orientation of the reaction. The three possible
  disubstituted products—ortho, meta, and para—are usually not formed
  in equal amounts.

Instead, the nature of the substituent already present
on the benzene ring determines the position of the second substitution.
An -OH group directs substitution toward the ortho and para positions,
for instance, while a carbonyl group such as -CHO directs substitution
primarily toward the meta position

All meta-directing
groups are strongly deactivating, and most ortho- and para-directing groups are
activating. **The halogens are unique in being ortho- and para-directing but
weakly deactivating.**

See screenshot below

[image: Classification of substituent effects in electrophilic aromatic substitution.]

*Taken from  Organic Chemistry (Mc Murry) 8th ED*

Comment: Does this also apply alkyl benzene?

Comment: Yes, the positioning of the electrophile will depend on the substituent, the substituent can be an alkyl group, alkene, aryl. What matters is whether the substituent group exterts an electronic withdrawal or donating effect. From the illustration above you can notice the alkyl group has an electron donating effect, conversely, the common characteristic of deactivating groups is that they are electron withdrawing.

Comment: So Bromine is ortho and para directing but which one is more likely to happen?

Comment: Both -ortho and -para intermediates are stable, however a higher ratio of the para substituted product is formed to enhance the stability of the Π system (since this configuration results in the substituents bring furthest away)

Comment: Meant being furthest*