# Electrophilic substitution on disubstituted benzene rings

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

If I have a strong deactivating group (like nitro) and a weak activating group (like methyl) attached to the benzene ring, which group's preference will direct the next substitution on the benzene ring? For example, if a chloro group is attached to meta-nitrotoluene, where will it substitute?

If I have both strong activating and also deactivating groups in the benzene ring, which position will be preferred for the next electrophilic substitution? For example, if I want to attach a chloro group to the meta-nitroaniline, where will it substitute?

Comment: Im not sure if I understood correctly, but I vaguely remember answering a similar question, not sure if it addreses your question but its found here: [Rules for benzene halogenation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70107/rules-for-benzene-halogenation/70116#70116)

Comment: if I want to attach a chlorine group to the meta-nitrotoluene, where will be chlorine attached ? @xavier_fakerat

Comment: For that you may refer to this site: [Electrophilic Substitution of Disubstituted Benzene Rings](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/benzrx2.htm) but if you wish to have that summarised, I could make an answer for it. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It helps a lot. But this link does not deal with strong deactivating and weak activating group combined  at benzene ring like meta-nitrotoluene. Would you please clarify  the question :
if I want to attach a chlorine group to the meta-nitrotoluene, where will be chlorine attached ?" . Thanks in advance . @xavier_fakerat

Comment: To prevent a homework-answer scenario, I had to explain the concepts so you understand and be able to apply. Generally. I dislike this approach (question-direct answer) because it has long term negative consequences. So that is why I give **Conceptual answers,** once you get the concept you will apply it anywhere and still pass, suceed etc.. It may be a bit of content but trust me it helps :).

Comment: Yes , after observing your answer style, I understand that you don't want to answer directly. To give conceptual answer is a good approach. :). But some time,some students may not get it as the concept is written. Thank you sir

Comment: This is a very good question and a common one among students of organic chemistry. I removed the sentence asking about the directing effect of diazonium, because that really doesn't fit with the the rest of what you're asking. If you would like, you can submit another question about that.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my question style. @jerepierre .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Electrophilic Substitution of Disubstituted Benzene Rings**

When a benzene ring has two substituents, each substituent exerts an effect on subsequent substitution reactions.

> Electrophilic substitution of a disubstituted benzene ring is governed
>   by the same resonance and inductive effects that affect
>   monosubstituted rings. The only difference is that it’s necessary to
>   consider the additive effects of two different groups.

- If the directing effects of the two groups reinforce each other, the situation is straightforward. In p-nitrotoluene, for example, both the methyl and the nitro group direct further substitution to the same position (ortho to the methyl and meta to the nitro). A single product is thus formed on electrophilic substitution.

[image]

From above, the methyl and the nitro group direct further substitution to the same position (ortho to the methyl and meta to the nitro). This is similar case with chlorine.

- If the directing effects of the two groups oppose each other, the more powerful activating group has the dominant influence, but mixtures of products are often formed.
- Further substitution rarely occurs between the two groups in a meta-disubstituted compound because this site is too hindered. Aromatic rings with three adjacent substituents must therefore be prepared by some other route, such as by substitution of an ortho-disubstituted compound.

You may also wish to review this table showing positions where common substituents direct:

[image]

Basing on the above explanations,  it is easy to predict the products of  electrophilic substitution of disubstituted benzene ring, the only thing you have to know is the effect of each substituent whether it is activating or deactivating. In some cases, observe the positions of the substituents as point 3 mentions steric effects may come into play and substitution may not occur.

On the second note, concerning diazonium ion, I think you have to look at measured dipole moments, experimental data etc I doubt if there is a way of telling whether a substituent is strongly deactivating by merely looking at it

---

**After explaining concepts now lets see what the answer for the question in comments will look like:**

[image]

**Reasons**

- the directing effects are opposing (nitro is meta while methyl is both ortho and para directing) but the methyl is more activating so we have a mixture:

  1. meta to nitro and methyl
  2. ortho to the methyl but para to the nitro

In this scenario since position 3 is not deactivated by nitro group hence there is also a possibility of a mixture here, also take note of how the nitro group is strongly deactivating at position 4 (more additive effect)

Hope this helps

References

- McMurry Organic chemistry
- [Electrophilic Substitution of Disubstituted Benzene Rings](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/benzrx2.htm)

Comment: Thanks. So between activating and deactivating groups, always activating groups are preferred (even the activating group is weak).right ? Except Stearic Hindrance effect.

Comment: I think this had to do with charge stabilisation. When one substituent has a pair of non-bonding electrons available for adjacent charge stabilization (e.g some activators like -OH), it will normally exert the product determining influence, even though it may be overall deactivating

Comment: Thank you, The group which has lone pair electrons and if it can stabilize the adjacent atom, will be preferred. So if OH and nitro are present, OH is preferred. Right,sir ?

Comment: That only applies to case 2 :) otherwise you just look at all possible outcomes (the three points)

Comment: And, for your last reaction, I want to know about meta-nitrotoluene but you explain about ortho-nitrotoluene.. meta-nitrotoluene has a problem as two group oppose. neither toluene or nitro has lone pair. So which group will be preferred ? Sir I understand many things but the answer of this question is still in confusion. :-(

Comment: Thanks let me remove that specific reaction, and place the nitro on meta ;)

Comment: Fixed! There you go Like I said before its similar, you just have to apply concepts :)

Comment: sir,as far as I know,is not it also called ortho-nitrotoluene? as NO2 is attached to the adjacent  to the methyl? Thank you for noticing... This is from wiki:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-Nitrotoluene

Comment: You are very right :)

Comment: Thank you sir for  all of these. :-) .  So as there is methyl and nitro group, we now get mixture. But if there is amino or hydroxy group instead of methyl , we may have get most of the products preferred by hydroxy or amino group.